# Converting a block of mixed binary/text data (unsigned char) into a widestring (std::wstring) while ignoring nulls and invalid characters

Tags: c++, regex, tcp

I'm tinkering with making a specific flavor of packet-inspection firewall that can read a packet from a given source, look at its content, and then selectively drop it. Thanks to WinDivert, I already have code that works sufficiently enough to deliver the payload portion of a packet into an unsigned char * and pass the whole packet on untouched, so I can watch packet payloads flow through my app skeleton.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to convert the contents of a TCP packet's payload into a widestring that can be analyzed, e.g., given some regex love, so that I can drop it if it contains unwanted data. Complicating the issue is this: the payload is raw, and can (read: WILL) contain additional data that doesn't translate into Unicode characters, such as zeroes and non-printable command codes. What I'd like to do is step through the unsigned-char packet payload and copy everything that is a valid character over to a widestring, and skip everything that isn't a valid character, including nulls. (The source length will be limited by the packet payload size, nut null-terminated, so extraneous nulls can be skipped safely.)

My issue is that I'm just not familiar enough with messing with string conversion in C++ to make headway.

Environment is Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.

Comment: And how are you sure what encoding the source has? Without knowing that, there is no meaningful conversion to UTF16, and neither it is possible to decide what bytes are invalid. (And even if you know, you'll always keep some bytes that are considered valid but not actual text)

Comment: Apart from that you don't even know the encoding data might span packet boundaries, so you don't know if the single 8 bit char at the end of a packet is just binary or if it is the beginning of an UTF-8 sequence which gets continued in the next TCP packet. And how about compressed data (i.e. Content-Encoding: gzip within HTTP).

Comment: You'd have to unpack the packet first. And somehow, get the encoding. If it's ascii, no problem, mfc has macro's. If the encoding is utf-8, you'd have to use a function to convert it to utf-16,  I'm not sure if MS has routines to do that. Then, of course when done, there is that surrogate pair thing to contend with.

Comment: @deviantfan - For flexibility I have to contend with whatever comes down the pipe. That said, the most likely is going to be Unicode as the typical packet source will generally be international.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Fortunately, my target data sources are (thus far, at least) all sending text as two-byte-per-char in big-endian order, so it looks like UTF-16 (without BOM) to me. The target source are also length-limiting and only using single packets, so spanning shouldn't be an issue. I will be ignoring compression and simply relaying packets with unhandled internals as-is.

Comment: @sln - Already doing the packet deconstruction, with headers being stripped from the payload. The payload comes in without any encoding markers and can include unknown non-character data, but the encoding looks to the eye to be consistent UTF-16. Basically I want to copy everything in each packet that can be read as UTF-16 to a widestring and ignore/skip anything that can't.

Comment: Utf-16 and wstring type, exist as 2 bytes (surrogates as a pair of 2 bytes). You might have to convert it to a 4 byte long, then run a regex on it to strip out anything not within the Unicode code point range.

Comment: `For flexibility I have to contend with whatever comes down the pipe` Well that's impossible. `That said, the most likely is going to be Unicode` "Unicode" isn't an encoding. I know 7 basic ones X 2 endianess states X BomOrNot = strictly speaking at least 28 possibilites of Unicode. Maybe you should get more familier with what Unicode actually is before doing something like this. Also don't forget to read about normalization etc.etc.

Comment: (Reading the next comment, I see that you indeed do know something, but I'm leaving the comment there because there might be some new keyword for you)

Comment: @deviantfan - Impossible? No. Complicated, possibly to the point of absurdity? Certainly. At this point I have a wchar_t array of each packet's payload after running the raw through MultiByteToWideChar, but still have garbage characters and nulls. I'm thinking that I'll need to just do what **sln** is suggesting and step through the payload, checking 4 bytes at a time for UTF-32 and 16BE/LE with surrogates, then in 2-byte pairs for whether it's 16LE or BE , then single bytes if it's 8. Should thus be possible to determine the Unicode flavor with one packet's payload.